# When the electric field EMF radiation hits tin foil why does it result in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, shielding, emf

I have a cheap Erickhill EMF reader that measures “electric field” and “magnetic field”.

I’ve been experiencing an odd phenomena that I can’t quite explain of a electrical sound emanating from a particular area. I feel as if the source is on the first floor of the building directly below my location on the second floor. It sounds like magnetostrsiction possibly and is sort of like a pulsing oscillation of a brief period of higher intensity  and then 2-3 seconds of lower intensity in terms of what I can sense. A multimeter reading taken at an outlet with nothing plugged in where measures a small .1-.3v change in voltage that is in sync with higher then lower intensity oscillation.

My EMF meter reads an electric field reading in the 500-700 volt/m range and nothing in terms of magnetic field.

As an experiment, I placed a piece of decent quality heavy duty aluminum foil about 2 feet in length directly  on the floor which is made of large vinyl material imitation wood planks above bare concrete. When I place the EMF reader on top of the foil the electric field reading drops to zero and is replaced by a magnetic field reading which is just within the meter’s danger zone. I’ve only really seen magnetic field readings on the meter from
actual magnets.

Can anyone explain why the electric field is converting into a magnetic field as a result of the aluminum foil? I understand how foil acts as a shield and that conductors block emf effectively but is it normal for the electric field to become a magnetic one?

Comment: Well, a conductor in any electrical field will experience a current. That's what an electrical field does. Any current causes a magnet field. That's what a current does. But you already knew that – you're running around with EM detecting equipment, so you most definitely learned the basics at some point! Might be worth to re-visit these basics.

Comment: Have you considered **going downstairs and telling your neighbour** their equipment is making an annoying sound and asking if they'd mind moving it or installing sound dampening material?